# php7 - php-fpm sock not found after configure

Tags: php, sockets, debian, php-7

I try to install php7 on Debian 8.

I would like configure php-fpm with a socket insteed of a port number.

I have enable `--enable-sockets`during php configure. But I have no socket.

How I can found this socket and install it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a socket instead of a port number, you change your [php-fpm configuration file](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php), specifically the following pool directive

> `listen` string: The address on which to accept FastCGI requests. Valid syntaxes are: 'ip.add.re.ss:port', 'port', '/path/to/unix/socket'. This option is mandatory for each pool.

In other words, set this to something like `/var/run/fpm.sock`.

Make sure that this socket is the same socket your webserver is using, for example in Nginx you will have a config entry like this:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fpm.sock;
```

If this doesn't match your listen directive, fpm will not respond to requests by your webserver.

Refer to this article for more information:

- https://serversforhackers.com/video/php-fpm-configuration-the-listen-directive